# Could not cast value of type 'NSNull' (0x1b9059de8) to 'NSDictionary' (0x1b9056b58). getting in flutter_stripe IOS Flutter app

Tags: flutter, stripe-payments, flutter-stripe

I am using flutter_stripe 9.4.0, this code is working fine on android device but when I run on IOS it gives an error and app crashes
**Error is:  Could not cast value of type 'NSNull' (0x1b9059de8) to 'NSDictionary' (0x1b9056b58)**.

I also used Stripe.publishableKey = "*******" in main method as well.
and platform :ios, '13.0'

**This is my flutter code:**

```
Future<void> makePayment() async {
    print("1");
    String totalPrice = (_subtotal+_audiototal+_singleAudiototal).toStringAsFixed(2);
    int totalPriceAsInt = int.parse(totalPrice.split('.')[0]);
    print("2");
    try {
      paymentIntentData = await createPaymentIntent(totalPriceAsInt.toString(), 'USD');



      // Check if cart items are already purchased
      final bool itemsAlreadyPurchased = await checkCartItemsPurchased();
      print("4");

      if (itemsAlreadyPurchased) {
        // Show a toast message indicating that items are already purchased
        ToastMessage.showMessage("Some items in the cart are already purchased.");
        print("5");

      } else {
        print("6");
        print(paymentIntentData);
        print(paymentIntentData!['client_secret']);
        print(paymentIntentData!['customer']);
        print(paymentIntentData!['ephemeralKey']);
        await Stripe.instance.initPaymentSheet(
          paymentSheetParameters: SetupPaymentSheetParameters(
            customFlow: false,
            paymentIntentClientSecret: paymentIntentData!['client_secret'],
            merchantDisplayName: 'Body and mind',
            customerId: paymentIntentData!['customer'],
            customerEphemeralKeySecret: paymentIntentData!['ephemeralKey'],
            googlePay: null,
            applePay: null,
            style: ThemeMode.system,

          ),

        );
        print("7");

        await displayPaymentSheet();
        print("8");

        if (paymentSuccessful) {
          await handlePurchase();
          print("9");
        }
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print("9");
      print("exception error or some-other error: $e");
    }
  }


  Future<bool> checkCartItemsPurchased() async {
    final cartController = Get.put(CartController());
    final cartCourses = await cartController.getCartCourses();
    final cartAudioPackages = await cartController.getCartAudioPackages();
    final cartSingleAudio = await cartController.getCartSingleAudios();

    if (cartCourses.isNotEmpty || cartAudioPackages.isNotEmpty || cartSingleAudio.isNotEmpty) {
      User? user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
      if (user == null) {
        return false;
      }

      // Check courses
      if (cartCourses.isNotEmpty) {
        for (final cartCourse in cartCourses) {
          // Check if the course is already purchased
          final isCoursePurchased = await isItemAlreadyPurchased(cartCourse.id.toString(), 'coursePurchases');
          if (isCoursePurchased) {
            return true; // Stop and return true if any course is already purchased
          }
        }
      }

      // Check audio packages
      if (cartAudioPackages.isNotEmpty) {
        for (final cartAudioPackage in cartAudioPackages) {
          // Check if the audio package is already purchased
          final isAudioPurchased = await isItemAlreadyPurchased(cartAudioPackage.id.toString(), 'audioPurchases');
          if (isAudioPurchased) {
            return true; // Stop and return true if any audio package is already purchased
          }
        }
      }

      // check for single audio
      if (cartSingleAudio.isNotEmpty) {
        for (final cartAudioPackage in cartSingleAudio) {
          // Check if the audio package is already purchased
          final isAudioPurchased = await isItemAlreadyPurchased(cartAudioPackage.id.toString(), 'single_audio_purchased');
          if (isAudioPurchased) {
            return true; // Stop and return true if any audio package is already purchased
          }
        }
      }
    }

    return false; // Return false if no items are already purchased
  }

  displayPaymentSheet() async {
    try {
      if (paymentIntentData != null) {
        await Stripe.instance.presentPaymentSheet(
          options: PaymentSheetPresentOptions(
            timeout: 2,
          ),
        );


        setState(() {
          paymentIntentData = null;
          paymentSuccessful = true;
        });



      } else {

      }
    } catch (e) {
      print("exception display sheet $e");
    }
  }


  createPaymentIntent(String amount,String currency)async{
    try{
      print("final Amount is");
      print(calculateAmount(amount));
      Map<String,dynamic>  body = {
        'amount':calculateAmount(amount),
        'currency':currency,
        'payment_method_types[]':'card',
      };

      final response = await http.post(Uri.parse('https://api.stripe.com/v1/payment_intents'),
          body: body,
          headers: {
            'Authorization':'Bearer *********',
            'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
          }
      );
      return jsonDecode(response.body.toString());
    }catch(e){
      print("exception error or some-other error: $e");
    }
  }

  calculateAmount(String amount){
    final price = int.parse(amount)*100;
    return price.toString();
  }
```

Flutter sdk version is: 3.13.1

Comment: Do you know exactly which line is causing that error to be surfaced? Is it the one where you pass `null` for `applePay` and `googlePay` while initializing the payment sheet?

Answer (score 0):

I solve this error by downgrade flutter_stripe package version. I was using flutter_stripe: 9.4.0 and error solve with flutter_stripe 7.0.0
I am not sure, it will work for every one but it worked for me.